# getContext(2d) from dynamically added canvas with jquery

Tags: jquery

Bit of a newbie here and probably out of my depth but I'm looping over some imported xml and appending a container with a div and then appending that with a canvas, I'm then trying to draw into that canvas. All I get is 'getContext() is not a function' Any guidance gratefully received

```
var newCanvas = 
    $('<canvas/>', {'class':'cnvsClass'}, {'id': 'theCanvas'})
    .width(215)
    .height(217);


$("#innerWrapper")
    .append($('<div/>', {'class': 'wrapper'})
        .append($(newCanvas)));



// Have tried  $('<canvas/>', $('.cnvsClass'), $("#theCanvas")
// I've added [0] after the selector but all I get is 
// TypeError: $(...).getContext is not a function
var ctx = $("#theCanvas").getContext("2d");

var image = new Image();
image.src = "AtlasSheet.png";  
$(image).load(function() {
    ctx.drawImage(image, 830,1165, 215, 217, 0, 0, 215, 217);    
});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need native DOM object to do it.

Try this;

```
var ctx = $("#theCanvas").get(0).getContext("2d");
```

Comment: Thanks @qqq tried that and I get $(...).get(...) is undefined - I've hard coded this and it works fine with: <div id="innerWrapper">
<div id="sprite1" style="position:absolute; width:16.4404296875%; height:19.596354166666664%;">
<canvas id="newCanvas" width="215" height="217"></canvas>
 </div><!--//END INNER WRAPPER--> canvas = document.getElementById("newCanvas");  
                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
    
        var image = new Image();  
    image.src = "AtlasSheet.png";  
    $(image).load(function() {
  ctx.drawImage(image, 830,1165, 215, 217, 0, 0, 215, 217);    
    });

Comment: Undefined, because of you did not give an `id` while creating it. Change your code: `$('<canvas/>', {'class':'cnvsClass', 'id': 'theCanvas'})`

Comment: Like I said - totally out of my depth! but thank you SO much @qqq ! that worked! Though I'm puzzled, I know that the canvas size reverts to 2:1 ratio when no size is specified and that's what it's done. I've tried $('<canvas/>', {'class':'cnvsClass', 'id': 'theCanvas', 'width': '215', 'height':'217' }) - any ideas?