# Canvas and jQuery: why doesn't getContext()

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13084918/html5-canvas-jquery-getcontext-on-classes) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796194/canvas-getcontext2d-returns-null) but there's no solution for my problem. If I create a canvas with jQuery then recall it through `document.getElementById()` i can call `getContext('2d')` and it works. Like this:

```
var ctx =
    $('<canvas />')
    .attr({
        id: 'canvasMenuSmall',
        width: '500px',
        height: '500px'
    })
    .appendTo('body');
var c=document.getElementById("canvasMenuSmall"),
    ctx=c.getContext('2d');
```

But if I try to immediately call `getContext('2d')` on the object it doesn't work with the error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`:

```
var ctx =
    $('<canvas />')
    .attr({
        id: 'canvasMenuSmall',
        width: '500px',
        height: '500px'
    })
    .appendTo('body')
    .getContext('2d'); // error raised
```

How comes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code does not work because you're trying to getContext [of jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/), not the DOM element. Don't chain `getContext` to the `appendTo`, but rather, use jQuery to get the element.

The working statement would be

`$().appendTo("#place")[0].getContext()`

rather than

`$().appendTo("#place").getContext()`

Comment: I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647629/getcontext2d-from-dynamically-added-canvas-with-jquery I just had to get the real DOM objet using `get(0)`

Comment: Yes, that works as well. I would personally have the `getContext()` on its own statement for better readability.

Comment: `.get(0).getContext('2D')` can be appended to the end of the original query after `appendTo`, although that is a bit harder to read as it ends the jQuery chain, imoho. I would simply do: `var ctx = ..; ctx.get(0).getContext('2D');`

Comment: @user2864740 Yes, that's what Olivier here said in his first comment. I knew what he was talking about. I edited the question to allow for both options.

Comment: Use `jq[0]` or `jq.get(0)`, not `jq.get()[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

`.getContext('2d')` is not a jQuery related stuff... It a method of a dom object.

`.getElementById()` returns a dom element, that's why it works there.